# How to call Mongoose Find function to fetch all of the documents as an array?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, async-await, es6-promise, mutability

I am still new to Node.js and Mongoose and have no idea why this code is not returning an array. Any suggestions?

```js
function all(array){
    array = card.cards.find({}, (err, items) => {
        array = items
        return array
    })
}

let arr = []
all(arr)
console.log(arr)
```

The end result is just an empty array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Also reassigning the parameter name to a new array does *nothing* to the array you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass in an array, you can return the items that are returned by the .find() method.

```
function getAll(){
    card.cards.find({})
         .then(items => {
             return items 
         }
         .catch(err => {
             console.log(err)
         }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't work cuz you still not return the result. The correct answer will be `function getAll() { return card.cards.find({}); }`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.

#### 1. No way to reassign variable passed as parameter inside a function:

```js
var a = 1;
function fn(b) {
  b = 2;
}
fn(a);
a === 1; // true
```

Also it's a bad pattern to mutate data inside functions when it's not really needed. Better just return and assign in outer scope:

```js
function all() {
  return card.cards.find({});
}
all(a).then(console.log); // [...]
```

But you can mutate an array without reassigning:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
function fn(array) {
  array.splice(0, Infinity, ...[5, 6, 7, 8]);
}
a; // [1, 2, 3]
fn(a);
a; // [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

#### 2. Async calls to Mongoose and async-await/promises

Still even if you return that from function `all` you have to wait the result.

Calls to mongoose methods are async. It means they return Promise objects (or promises) that implements interface with methods `then` and `catch`. The function you pass to `then` method will be called if promise will be resolved successfully, and the function in `catch` will be called if the promise will be rejected.

E.g.

```js
function p() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return Promise.resolve(1);
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error('2'));
  }
}

p()
  .then(function (result) { /* will be called half of time for resolve branch */ })
  .catch(function (error) { /* will be called for reject branch */ })
```

This code is similar to but uses syntactic sugar:

```js
async function p() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) return 1; // Similar to return Promise.resolve(1);
  throw new Error('2'); // Similar to return Promise.reject(new Error('2'))
}
```

To wait promises inside async function there is an `await` keyword.

```js
async function all() {
  try {
    return await cards.find({});

  } catch(error) {
    if (false /* somehow handle mongoose errors */) {
      // check error, if db not ready just retry or do sth else
      // …
    }

    // Just rethrow if we can't do any
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Read more about async-await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function